# Suitable CPU with RTX3070 GPU for deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gpu

I am trying to get a GPU for my deep learning research. Due to stock limitation, I can only get a RTX3070. In my lab, there's some PC/workstation whereby I can install the RTX3070. However, I wonder if the CPU is suitable. Will it cause bottleneck with the GPU. I used the [bottleneck calculator](https://pc-builds.com/calculator/) to check.

but it's more suitable for games. They mention that 1 and 3 below are not suitable but I'm not sure how accurate it is.

Does anyone have experience how to check?

The CPUs I have are:

1. i7-4770@3.4ghz PC 32gb ram
2. xeon 4216@2.1ghz 192 ram
3. xeon e5520@2.27ghz 64gb ram

RAM, PSU and SSD can be upgraded so it's not a big problem. The main task is deep learning.

Comment: Sorry, I think this kind of question is out of topic. My advice: if you're doing DL research in any decent lab/university, you should have access to some kind of high performance cluster, ask around.